# error in fresh eclipse and tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have problems with eclipse and tomcat. I even installed new version of eclipse (Version: Kepler Service Release 1). I don't have any project jet - i just want to run server. I have tomcat installed on my computer - it works OK with NetBeans.

My problem is, that I can not rut tomcat with eclipse. I added tomcat server `(window->preferiences->runtime enviroment)`. Also in menu `file->other->server`, Tomcat has been added.

My problem is, that every time I click "Start" on my tomcat server the following error occurs:

```
publishing to tomcat v7.0 server at localhost has encountered a problem. Publishing the configuration
Publishing the configuration...
Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache Tomcat 7.0.34/backup\catalina.policy: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.34\backup\catalina.policy (System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki)
    C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.34\backup\catalina.policy (System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki)
    Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache Tomcat 7.0.34/backup\catalina.properties: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.34\backup\catalina.properties (System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki)
    C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.34\backup\catalina.properties (System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki)
    Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache Tomcat 7.0.34/backup\context.xml: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.34\backup\context.xml (System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki) (....)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try run the eclipse as Admin (Right click on shortcut -> "Run as Administrator").